# Rails nested concerns not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here is my `routes.rb` file:

```
  concern :commentable do
    resources :comments do
      get 'cancel'
    end
  end


  concern :uploadable do
    resources :uploads, concerns: [:commentable], shallow: true do
    end
  end


  concern :workable do
    resources :work_orders, concerns: [:commentable, :uploadable], path: 'workorders', shallow: true do
    end
  end


  resources :locations, concerns: [:workable, :commentable, :uploadable] do
    get 'partner/add'
    get 'partner/remove'
  end
```

The short version of the story is that I added the :upload able concern to Locations and it works fine along with comentable.  So these work:

`Location.last.uploads => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` and `Location.last.comments => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

but these do NOT:

`WorkOrder.last.uploads NoMethodError: undefined method 'uploads' for #<WorkOrder:0x007f9c242cf110>`

I am missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WorkOrder.last.uploads NoMethodError: undefined method 'uploads' for #

It seems you have missed `has_many` relations for model `WorkOrder`:

```
class WorkOrder
   has_many :uploads, as: :uploadable  #... seems it should be polymorphic
end
```

Please NOTE what routing mechanism, isn't the same as model relations. So the first declares management to handle requests for controllers, and the last one defined relations berween models. In most cases the naming agreenment is the same as for models, but it uses quite independent mechnism of rails.

Comment: Yup - it was as obvious as that. I forgot to go back and add that to my models. It was a late night :). Thanks!

Comment: It is not a good idea to use polymorphic in rails.  The issue is the database has no idea where the FK 's point back to which can lead to missing parent/child relationships.